# Laravel - set checkbox / radio selected in edit mode

Tags: php, laravel-4

In Laravel, we can set the value for a form field element with this:

```
{{Form::text('name', 'predefined name')}}
```

The above work well, even in the edit mode the `predefined name` will always appear in the text field. However, for checkbox and radio button, it does not work.

```
{{Form::checkbox('country', 'UK',true)}}
{{Form::radio('gender', 'male',true)}}
{{Form::radio('gender', 'female',false)}}
```

No matter what I set for the checkbox & radio button, it will be ignored and use the data from database. This become an huge trouble for array of checkbox.

```
{{Form::checkbox('country[]', 'UK',true)}}
{{Form::checkbox('country[]', 'SG',false)}}
{{Form::checkbox('country[]', 'US',false)}}
```

How can I solve it? Thank you.

Comment: Have you bind the model into your form using `Form::model`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the visibility of the value of a checkbox or radio-array:
Usually you will add text to a checkbox or radio-element via a label.

```
{{ Label::for('nameOfInput', 'Value') }}
```